# In Xcode Interface Builder how do I control how the element behave when the view is resized?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

In older Xcode I have a little window where I could mark braces and band things to control how a NSView behaves when its parent is resized. In the new Xcode that is missing and the controls are doing whatever they feel like.

Is there any way to get this control back? (current version: Version 4.3.2 (4E2002))

Comment: I definitely want to know about that too (actually one of the few reasons I hesitate upgrading to the last version)... VERY good point! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Xcode 4.3 when you create a Cocoa application project, the xib file uses auto layout. Auto layout replaces the size inspector's autosizing mask.

If you want to use the autosizing mask, the solution is to turn off auto layout. Select the xib file from the project navigator, open the file inspector, and deselect the Use Auto Layout checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Read [*Constraints Express Relationships Between Views*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/constraintFundamentals.html) to learn how views are constrained in Xcode 4. In fact, you probably want the entire [*Cocoa Auto Layout Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-SW1).

Briefly, when you add a view to your view hierarchy, it comes with some constraints. Select the view in the and you'll see some blue lines that look a bit like I-beams -- these represent the constraints. Click on one of them and you can edit its properties in the attributes inspector. But how you should set the attributes probably won't make much sense until you've read about how constraints work in the document linked above.

Comment: that link does not explain how to set anything in interface builder, there is no GUI for this any more? I have to set it all in code with some ASCII-Art Format String thing? What took 10 min. will now take hours!

Comment: @Justin808 You don't need to edit constraints in code -- you can do it in the attributes inspector as described in my edit, but read the docs first.

Comment: Time to read, but this new thing is 100 times more complex than the old way. Wish I could turn it off.